# Project structure for microservices

Tags: structure, microservices, project

One of the project I am working the project architect is saying that we should make each layer as a separate maven project for e.g. For entity beans there is one maven project for dao interfaces separate project dao impl there is another project service interface there is one project service impl there is another project and controller is another project. In controller we are adding entity, dao and service project as dependency. Is it the right structure? What are the drawbacks and benefits of this structure? What should be the right way to micro services project structure?
We have 9 microservices so there are almost 40 projects. It feels clumsy.

Comment: This is an opinion based question and will probably be closed. There is possibly no right answer either. I'm hoping your build pipeline would be hopefully faster. When you'll build a microservice, the test run and compilation of the layers are not needed as they happened earlier when you built them. That is an advantage and important. It will quickly give the developer a feedback. Also, it may be easy for developers to understand the codebase.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make separate projects for things which are consumed directly by other microservices like Beans. For eg: and things which are part of microservice impl.

Why we need to make separate:

Service A has 5 Beans which are exposed on using API IServiceAAPI

Now Service B use Service A by using API IServiceAAPI(assuming your framework automatically create a IServiceAAPI Object which calls the actual service) and return one of the beans. So either you rewrite those beans of use the original API from Service A, as it helps when the API changes your code automatically get the updates.

In general it makes sense that you have one project named ServiceAAPI which contains API, Beans and other project named ServiceAImpl

Comment: If there are two service A (which is in project A which is related to user mgt.) and Service B (which is in project B which is related to some business process). There is something which is needed in service B from A and if i will use service A's bean  in service B directly as a dependency then will it not be a monolithic approach any change in service A's bean will may nee to make change in Service b. Will it not violate the micro services rules.

Comment: No it is not a Monolith approach. if you are not doing such things you will end up creating duplicate beans and duplicate API wrapper code. What i have seen is people do share such things to tackle code duplicay. Also lets take an example where you have ServiceA (userMgmt) Impl and  ServiceA(API) and if you are changing the ServiceA API in such a way that is incompatible then anyway your other service code will not work even if they are creating duplicate beans. These problems are handled by versioning, also if one service do breaking changes then there is a process to notify other services

Comment: If you wanted to use the service of other for e.g. you wanted something from BeanA then you can just create the method on that microservice and you can call it from other microservices(Rest Template etc.).